# Importing processing from QGIS into IDLE

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, standalone, idle

I have been trying to make a program that creates a virtual raster based on the files that are input. Whenever I run my code it says.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/Zach/Desktop/Python_testing/Geo_test_1.py", line 1, in
>
> import processing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'processing'

My code is:

```py
import processing 

file_input=['C:/Users/Zach/Desktop/Qgis/Missisipii_Delta/LC08_L1TP_021040_20201011_20201016_01_T1_B1.TIF'.... there are 7 more bands]
 
file_output = 'C:/Users/Zach/Desktop/Qgis/proc_build.TIF'
processing.run("gdal:buildvirtualraster",\
{'INPUT':file_input,\
'RESOLUTION':0,'SEPARATE':True,\
'PROJ_DIFFERENCE':False,\
'ADD_ALPHA':False,\
'ASSIGN_CRS':None,\
'RESAMPLING':0,\
'SRC_NODATA':'',\
'EXTRA':'',\
'OUTPUT':file_output})
```

I am not sure if this is the problem, but I installed GDAL through Anaconda, and Anaconda overall has seemed to bring a few complications. I do not know where to find processing in my directory, nor how to make it so that it works in IDLE. This code works fine in the QGIS Python Console. So, how to import processing from QGIS into IDLE?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: I am running QGIS 3.14.16. I uninstalled anaconda and I am going to get OSGeo4W and try to run through there. It seems that may make it easier for me to set the correct file paths as I feel that is the problem.